# Two mice connected to PC - how to ignore ones input

Tags: windows-7, usb, mouse, wireless-mouse

I have two wireless mice (one gaming mouse and one ergonomic) connected to a Windows 7 PC with Logitech's Unifying dongle.

My problem is sometimes (quite often) vibrations activates the ergonomic mouse when I'm gaming and interrupts my aiming. I'm looking for a software trick to ignore input from one of them. Then I can write a script that will block this input as soon as a game is launching. Now I have to manually on and off this mouse and it's super annoying.

If it will help I can use separate dongles for each mouse but I would rather use only one because my laptop has only 2 USB type A ports.

Comment: Turn it upside down, although some make great security motion sensors

Answer (score 2):

Try to deactivate it via the device manager. If it works you can write a script to turn it on/off.

If you consider using a second dongle, you could consider buying a USB hub with buttons to turn the individual ports on and off. Might be easier then unplugging/re-plugging the dongle.

A third option would be to disable/enable the mouse via Logitech's Unifying software.